# "She found golden hairs on his clothes." Why is it "hairs" and not "hair"?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage

I read in a novel "she found golden hairs on his clothes," and I want to know if it's correct. I have always heard that it's *hair,* not *hairs.*

Comment: Also see *[Is 'hair' singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9951)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct. It follows the standard subject + verb + object structure.

Comment: I mean to ask about hairs...i have always heard its hair

Comment: That's if it's singular. If she found more than one hair, then it is "hairs".

Comment: Ok thankyou that answers my question

Comment: *She found **a** hair* refers to just one strand of hair, but *she found hair* (without an article) doesn't specify number - she may have found one strand or multiple strands.